# Using foreach With Variables on Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

Currently, I have some code that matches DB data to array data and pulls the data out of an array that matches a service ID.

```
$get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM table WHERE serviceid=:serviceid");
$get->bindParam(':serviceid', $serviceid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$get->execute();
$result = $get->fetchAll();

$search_values = array();
$wanted_data = array();

foreach($result as $row) {
    $search_values[] = $row['data'];
}

foreach($data_bits as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value['data'], $search_values)) {
        $wanted_data[] = $data_bits[$key];
    }
}
```

My next step is to use the returned data and get a new array from it. I'm working with a json API. Below is what I currently have, but it does not work, but if I `var_dump` it returns all of the proper data. I just can't get it to appear correct on the Smarty page.

```
foreach($wanted_data as $more_data) {
        $ch_r = curl_init("https://api.url.com/data/".$more_data['name']."/info");
        curl_setopt($ch_r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch_r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer KEY REMOVED',
            'Content-Type: application/json')
        );

    $data_grab = curl_exec($ch_r);
    $data_grab = json_decode($data_grab, true);
    foreach ($data_grab['detailed_info'] as $data_key2 => $data) {
    $data_grab1 = $data_grab['detailed_info'][$data_key2];

        }
    }
```

Then again, if I `echo var_dump(data_grab1);` it will output all the records needed for each `$more_data['name']`, but on the Smarty output it does not. Below is Smarty:

```
{foreach key=key item=data from=$wanted_data}
    {foreach key=key item=more_data from=$data_grab1}
        {if $more_data.info_3 neq 'SN'}
                <tr><td>{$data.name}</td><td>{$more_data.info_6}</td><td>{$more_data.name}</td><td>{$more_data.info_3}</td><td>{$more_data.info_4}</td></tr>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

How do I get Smarty to properly output the data?

EDIT:
I should probably add that the Smarty template `foreach` loop `{$data.name}` returns the info just fine. It's the other table items using data from the second `foreach` that do not work.

`var_dump(data_grab1)`

```
['detailed_info'] =>  
    array(7) {
      ["info_4"]=>
      int(10243591)
      ["info_3"]=>
      string(2) "SN"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "SD"
      ["info_6"]=>
      string(20) "Some data"
    }
    array(7) {
      ["info_4"]=>
      int(10243592)
      ["info_3"]=>
      string(2) "SN"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "SM"
      ["info_6"]=>
      string(20) "Some more data"
    }
    array(7) {
      ["info_4"]=>
      int(10243593)
      ["info_3"]=>
      string(2) "SN"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "NO"
      ["info_6"]=>
      string(20) "Some tiny data"
    }
    array(7) {
      ["info_4"]=>
      int(10243594)
      ["info_3"]=>
      string(1) "HE"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "DB"
      ["info_6"]=>
      string(14) "BOLD data"
    }
    array(7) {
      ["info_4"]=>
      int(10243608)
      ["info_3"]=>
      string(1) "HE"
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "a hair of data"
      ["info_6"]=>
      string(7) "bold"
    }
```

Comment: In your second smarty foreach loop you reference `from=$more_data` however I can't see where $more_data is defined in the code you have provided?

Comment: Sorry. I changed the variables when posted here and mixed that up. It's fixed now as `data_grab1`

Comment: You define `$data_grab1` in nested foreach loops so it is being reset on every loop iteration, so the final value is just the last value set from the last loop. Don't you want to associate the value against the appropriate `$wanted_data` key?

Comment: That is what I want to do. I'm just not sure how exactly I would do it. Being fairly new to PHP, this speed bump has been rattling me.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `echo var_dump(data_grab1);`? Hide sensitive data if needed but mantain the structure.

Comment: `var_dump(data_grab1)` has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `$more_data` to the original array so that it is correctly associated.

In the below I added the `$key` in the foreach loop and then referenced the `$key` on the `$wanted_data` array to set the data you retrieve from the `curl_exec` to the existing data.

```
foreach($wanted_data as $key => $more_data) {
    $ch_r = curl_init("https://api.url.com/data/".$more_data['name']."/info");
    curl_setopt($ch_r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch_r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer KEY REMOVED',
        'Content-Type: application/json')
    );
    $data_grab = curl_exec($ch_r);
    $wanted_data[$key]['more_data'] = json_decode($data_grab, true);
}
```

Then in Smarty template you can run the second foreach loop on that array

```
{foreach key=key item=data from=$wanted_data}
    {foreach key=key item=more_data from=$data.more_data}
        {if $more_data.info_3 neq 'SN'}
                <tr><td>{$data.name}</td><td>{$more_data.info_6}</td><td>{$more_data.name}</td><td>{$more_data.info_3}</td><td>{$more_data.info_4}</td></tr>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Note: I've made some assumptions about the structure of your data and what comes from your `curl_exec`. You may need to output the data using `print_r` or `var_dump` to see the structure and modify the code as required.

Comment: That did it right there! Thank you! The only thing is in Smarty I had to `{foreach key=key item=more_data from=$data['detailed_info'].more_data}` because the `$data_grab1` array has `['detailed_info']` before the array. As long as I add `['detailed_info']` to Smarty it works just fine.